# Screen super zoomed in - Windows, how do I fix?

Tags: display, windows-11, resolution

Ok so, my screen is ridiculously zoomed in and I've changed the zoom settings but the LED display doesn't line up with the physical computer screen when I do that, and when I try to change the resolution size there's always a little extra negative space around my display that wasn't there before.

I've been thrown for a bit of a loop with this issue and I can't for the life of me figure out a solution, can anyone help?

Computer Type - Windows Surface Pro
Windows Version - Windows 11

If it helps anything I was playing a game I downloaded on Steam and when I exited out of that the screen was super whack

Comment: Try WinKey + Ctrl-M  to manage the magnifier

Comment: Sadly, did not work, only allowed me to zoom in more, not zoom out. But thank you kindly anyhow!! Even if it didn't work it's lots of help having different solutions to try!! :)

Comment: Ah, the [famous Kiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect)! It sounds likely that the Steam game changed the resolution of your screen, so now you have to change it back. https://youtu.be/1A7VBBIe7vk?t=13 It probably says "(Recommended)" next to the correct resolution.

Comment: There are 3 possible resolutions depending on which model of the Surface Pro you have 1920×1080, 2160×1440, or 2736×1824 pixels. Decent chance that if you play a different game on Steam it will set the resolution back to the correct settings btw. If all that doesn't help, press the Windows key + the Escape key.

Comment: My good fellow, thank you kindly! My screen is back to not hitting me in the face with half a display, thank you very very much for your help! I can now very happily enjoy a full screen that is actually a full screen, thank you! Hope you have a wonderful day today!

Comment: You are very welcome of course! Enjoy!